# mongoDB lock collection when updating javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, locking, real-time

I am building a DB function and I need to lock the read option on the documents select them and then unlock them. 
I found on the internet the option to findAndModify this function is exactly what I want but that updates only one document.

An example

```
db.people.findAndModify({
    query: { state: "USA" },
    sort: { rating: 1 },
    update: { $inc: { score: 1 } },
    upsert: true
})
```

so I have many that live in USA so I want to select all them and increase all of them.
I have two problems:
1.How do I lock Collection In MongoDB (didn't find any documentation on that).

2.How do I findAndUpdate many documents? cant use update cause this method isn't locking the DB when operating (at least I didn't find that it does lock, so I assuming that it doesn't).

Comment: 1. MMapv1 will actually lock collection on write but concurrency rules in MongoDB mean that it wont totally be that way. Wiredtiger will not lock collection, nor is there a function in MongoDB to block reads. This isn't how you really use MongoDB

Comment: 2. Simply, You cannot with upsert flag